# Reading/Writing MS Word files in Python

Tags: python, ms-word, read-write

Is it possible to read and write Word (2003 and 2007) files in Python without using a COM object?
I know that I can:

```
f = open('c:\file.doc', "w")
f.write(text)
f.close()
```

but Word will read it as an HTML file not a native .doc file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd look into [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) which intrinsically has access to windows/office APIs because it runs on .NET runtime.

Answer (score 38):

See [python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx), its official documentation is available [here](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

This has worked very well for me.

Note that this does not work for .doc files, only .docx files.

Comment: But it is supported .doc format, i tried but it throws me a ValueError `ValueError: file '<open file 'file.doc', mode 'r' at 0x7f29a1b5a6f0>' is not a Word file, content type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.themeManager+xml`

Comment: It is called python-docx not python-doc, so no. :)

Comment: @Damian but the question is also about .doc files, so you should note that your answer only applies to .docx files.

Comment: Any idea for opening .doc files then?

Answer (score 11):

If you only what to read, it is [simplest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516044/is-it-possible-to-read-word-files-doc-docx-in-python/30122239#30122239) to use the linux soffice command to convert it to text, and then load the text into python:

Comment: +1 I dont know why this gets a negative voting. This is sometimes the only solution and sometimes it's enough.

Answer (score 3):

doc (Word 2003 in this case) and docx (Word 2007) are different formats, where the latter is usually just an archive of xml and image files. I would imagine that it is very possible to write to docx files by manipulating the contents of those xml files. However I don't see how you could read and write to a doc file without some type of COM component interface.