# Is there a python library for editing msword doc files?

Tags: python, ms-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading/Writing MS Word files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python)

I know there are some libraries for editing excel files but is there anything for editing msword 97/2000/2003 .doc files in python? Ideally I'd like to make some minor changes to the formatting of the text based on the contents of the text. A really trivial example would be highlighting every word starting with a capital.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not look at using [python-uno](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) to load the document into OpenOffice and manipulate it using the UNO interface. There is some example code on the site I just linked to which can get you started.

Comment: It might be good to say how to get access to XScriptContext, since it doesn't come with Python.

Answer (score 3):

If platform independence is important, then I'd recommend using the OpenOffice API either through BASIC or Python. OpenOffice can also run in headless mode, without a GUI, so you can automate it for batch jobs. These links might be helpful:

- [(BASIC) Text Documents in OpenOffice](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Structure_of_Text_Documents)
- [(Python) Examples](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_samples)

It's definitely more involved than importing a module and doing a string replace, but OpenOffice is probably the best free .doc reader, that you can hook into.

Answer (score 1):

The [PyWin32](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) library allows you to access COM objects from Python, including all of the various Office COM APIs. I won't claim it's **easy** to use, but it does work.

Comment: Any idea how to do that in Linux?

Comment: Newer office files could possibly be handled with mono, but I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376221/programmatic-mail-merge-style-data-injection-into-existing-excel-spreadsheets), I found out about [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/), which uses [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). POI has many subcomponents, including HWPF:

> HWPF is our port of the Microsoft Word
>   97 file format to pure Java. It
>   supports read, and limited write
>   capabilities. Please see the HWPF
>   project page for more information.
>   This component is in the early stages
>   of development. It can already read
>   and write simple files.

Since this is a Java library, it could be scripted using Jython. I don't know how good the writing capabilities are yet, but please post a comment back if it helps.