# Create PDF from Word template in Python

Tags: python

I need to generate reports in python. The report needs to contain a header and footer on each page, some text that won't change, some text that's dynamic, and some charts.

I've created a template using Word, and I'm looking for a way of replacing placeholders such as [+my_placeholder+] with text content/charts/whatever.

Is there anything that can let me use Word documents (or something Word can write) as a template to create a PDF in Python? Since I've already created sample reports in Word I want to reuse what I've got instead of having to recreate them using ReportLab or HTML (I know about ReportLab, pyPDF and also xhtml2pdf).

Comment: Use a HTML template instead of a .doc/.docx - It's much better.

Comment: The short answer to your question is - No. Use a template language to create templates.

Comment: @limelights - it's not much better for me because I'll have duplicate work :-)

Comment: Yes, but implementing an LibreOffice/OpenOffice connector that opens your wordfiles and reads, goes through the tedious WordML language, inserts data, copies it and then tries to convert it to a PDF will be more than your duplicate work.

Comment: @limelights Yes you may be right. I'll see if I can export the templates to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

about the first part, editing word templates, you can have a look at this question: [Reading/Writing MS Word files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python)

There is a package for editing word files, called [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

For converting word files into pdf documents, there should be a variety of different tools, including command line tools. So you could use python to edit your document and then use a converter tool that you call from your python code to create the pdf.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a good idea. Can I export the styles from my templates into that somehow? And I guess it doesn't rely on the Word binaries being installed (i.e. doesn't use COM)?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself so you would have to look into that.