# What python modules should I use to edit a word document then turn it to a pdf?

Tags: python, ms-word, pdf-generation, reporting

I want users to be able to create the report template in Microsoft Word, I'll then probably add document fields. Then the script evaluates a number of things adds the appropriate text to the fields then creates a pdf of the filled in form.

So which modules would be best for this? I've looked at reportlab but I need to work from a pre-generated template and that doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: There is also a [docx](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=python+docx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use it only under Windows, having Word installed you could use [PyWin32](http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/09/use-python-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-using-pywin32-library/) that lets you access the api of the suite. You could also try IronPython as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python).

If you need to read a docx template regardless of the platform you could try this [outdated extension](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx).

Comment: Thanks, IronPython certainly looks good. Only problem really is that though being cross-platform  isn't essential my main development environment is a mac and the target environment is win 7. I was going to explore [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) and convert to ODT myself from the .docx template. As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177799/good-pdf-report-generator-tool-for-python?rq=1).

Comment: that surely is a viable alternative (at least of the .docx template gets converted fine from Open|LibreOffice).

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your application to use a cloud service to populate Doc/DocX files there is a commercial system called [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) that can popluate plain-text (or merge) fields  and stream back populated PDF documents to your Python system, or deliver via email etc.

You would upload your "template" Doc files to Docmosis via the Website (or api calls) then invoke Docmosis using a https post from your Python code.

Please note I work for the company that created Docmosis.
Hope that helps.