# Importing word document in python

Tags: python, file

Can I import a word document into a python program so that its content can be read and questions can be answered using the data in the document. what would be procedure of using the data in the file

```
with open('animal data.txt', 'r')
```

i used this but is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading/Writing MS word files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python).

Comment: Your question is a little bit odd to me. You ask about a word document, but your example uses a `.txt` file, not a `.doc` or `.docx` file. What exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the file object to a variable using `as`:

```
with open('animal data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    ...
```

Now, `myfile` will be the file object and you can use it freely in the with-block.

Comment: Why do you think 'animal data.txt' is an invalid path? As a filename it works perfectly.

Comment: @RolandSmith - Oh, I see.  I misunderstood.  I thought he was trying to use `animal` as an executable or a directory.  Sorry. :*)

Answer (score 1):

Extracting data from a MS Word document involves a *lot* more than just reading it!

For reading modern Word documents with the `docx` extension you can use [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx). These documents are basically a bunch of XML files in a ZIP container.

Older `doc` files are basically undocumented binary blobs.