# Using Python (v2.7.6) to generate reports in Word

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am an absolute novice and was wondering if this would be a simple enough project for me.

I write loads of reports using pretty much the same group of paragraphs, which would only require minor changes each time (such as quantities, etc.).  Is it simple enough to write a script to automate this process?

Comment: It's simple if you know how to do it. To learn basic scripting from scratch might actually take a while. It sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx). It can create and update `docx` format Word documents.

The documentation starts with an [example](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using python to generate your reports in [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) or [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) format and then if you *have* to have Word as the final output run the output through a tool such as [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to produce what ever format you need.